# apache + nginx(for only one subdomain)

Tags: 12.04, server, apache2, nginx

I have a nice little Server with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Apache controlled by `plesk`.
Now I've installed `nginx` for my Gitlab subdomain.

But now nginx wants to control all.
How can I configure the nginx server to provide only one subdomain:
git.example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run them both on the same port. By default both will want to conquer `0.0.0.0:80` and that's not on. Two simple choices:

- Add an IP, bind nginx on its port 80, point DNS at that IP.
- Set nginx up on another port (eg 8080) and use Apache's ProxyPass directive to push one virtualhost back to nginx:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName git.example.com
      DocumentRoot /path/to/myapp/public
      ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

  This is actually quite common - just in reverse. Most people put nginx on the raw port 80 and let it handle raw file IO, and proxy back to Apache if they need something like mod_php. You could do that but it's very likely more work.

There are —as always— a hundred thousand million different ways of doing these sorts of things. These are the two main ones.